# Delete first line in fwrite function

Tags: php, csv, fwrite

I have a function in PHP that aims to download a csv file, but there is always a blank line at the start of the file

How to delete the blank line at the beginning of the file
this is my code

```
$name_file = 'ekspor-kag-bri-' . date('Ym', strtotime($data_pendukung['tgl_trf'])) . '.csv';
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name_file.'"');

        $kata_header = "REKENING;NOMINAL;EMAIL"."\n";
        $kata_header .= "tes";
        $arr_isi_cell = [];
        foreach ($dt_gaji as $row) {
            $isi_cell = str_replace("-","",$row->norekening) . ';' . floatval($row->total_gaji) . ';' . 'inayohanes@gmail.com'."\n";
            array_push($arr_isi_cell,$isi_cell);
        }
        $myfile = fopen("php://output", "wb");
        fwrite($myfile,$kata_header);
        foreach($arr_isi_cell as $line){
            // fputcsv($myfile,explode(',',$line),",");
            fwrite($myfile,$line);
        }

        fclose($myfile)
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the output.

Comment: in the last try, i tried using 'ob_flush' and it worked